# Can't import settings in Visual Studio 2008 SP1

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, vssettings

I recently baselined my machine and installed VS2008 and I am trying to import my settings file: http://naspinski.net/file.axd?file=naspinski.vssettings

I click **Tools->Import** Settings, **select Import selected environment settings** and click on **Next**

Next screen I select **No, just import new settings, overwrite my current settings** and click **Next**

I browse to my file and click **Open** -or- double-click on the file and it just dumps out... I don't get the option to click **Finished**, it just dumps out?

Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try only importing by section - you should then see which bits seem to be wrong...

Imports fine on my machine. = VS2008 sp1 - there are warnings on

1. Command Window Alises
2. External Tools

Might want to check them out.

Would also suggest changing to Monaco font - easier reading...

have a look at http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudioProgrammerThemesGallery.aspx

Comment: I cant even get to the screen where I choose the items... ?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had to add myself to the the Administrators group in Computer Management.  At work we do not have these privs by default.

Answer (score 0):

You're running on Vista or Server 2008, right?
Run Visual Studio as an administrator (right click shortcut and choose 'Run as admin').

This also happens with VS2005, only there it doesn't even bother to indicate failure. the security mechanism in Vista just reverts your settings as soon as you close visual studio.